# Can't use class from jar in netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans-8

[libraries properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8tFPB.png)

For one of my java courses, I need to import a pre-compiled java class in netbeans. I can't use it apparently.

So my prof is using grasp, which I don't like as IDE so I'm using netbeans. She is useless for my problem, so the problem here is that she has compiled the Joueur.class from java libraries and she wanted that we use it in our project. 
So I managed to transform the class in a jar file with jar.exe -cf, then I added it with right-clicking on libraries in my project in netbeans. 
Netbeans listed i,so it apparently recognized it. But when I try to use methods from it, it's underlined. But I've read that netbeans will recognized the contents of the jar automatically so I should be able to use it without a problem. 
Is there an import to do in the main package or something to use it? I can't find the information ...
[global netbeans](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oam9M.png)

Comment: When you added it to the jar did you put it in a directory that matched the package name of the class? For example, if the class is named (including the package) `x.y.MyClass` is the path to the class file `x/y/MyClass.class` in the jar?

Comment: No. I didn't do it. is that necessary?Because as I said, netbeans recognized the class in the list of the libraries. And in the properties of the libraries I can see the .jar correctly with his absolute path.
And sorry i'm new at this, it's already a miracle that I've managed to add it in netbeans.

I've put 2 screenshots to give you more general idea

Comment: By the way guys, It's useless to give bad appreciation about my question, I'm new and I'm already at one.

Comment: @pcarter I don't understand about the directory. if the libraries is linked to the project, why should I put it in the same directory than the classes already in my project? and in which directory ? in ../src/?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name of the package for the class has to match the directory path in the jar. So if you want to create the jar correctly for class `x.y.MyClass`, you need to create the directories for it, copy the class file to it and then use `jar` to create the jar file. Here are some example commands:

```
mkdir x
mkdir x\y
copy MyClass.class x\y
jar -cf MyJar.jar x
```

To verify, type the following:

```
jar -tf MyJar.jar
```

It should print out something like:

```
META-INF/
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
x/y/
x/y/MyClass.class
```